# Checking if database has data using node js, what's wrong with my if statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to see if users follow each other or already liking a post so that I can render a page with no errors. What I am getting is that if there is no data in the database (user is not following the post author or liking the current post) I will get an error and my app will crash: 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined**

I did an if statement but it doesn't seem to work. I did an if statement on another route with only one SELECT query and it works fine. I don't know where I went wrong...

My code:

```
if (req.user) { // if the user is currently logged in
  var q = 'SELECT * FROM follows WHERE followee_id =\'' + author_id + '\' AND follower_id =\'' + req.user.id + '\'';
  connection.query(q, function (err, resault) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var isfollowing = {
      follower_id: resault[0].follower_id,
      followee_id: resault[0].followee_id
    };

    var q = 'SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id =\'' + req.user.id + '\' AND post_id =\'' + post_id + '\'';
    connection.query(q, function (err, likes) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      var hasLikes = {
        user_id: likes[0].user_id,
        post_id: likes[0].post_id
      };

      if ((likes.length > 0) && (resault.length > 0)) { // if the user has likes and is following users
        console.log('has likes, has follows');
        res.render('single', {
          showPost: post,
          comments: comments,
          numComments: numComments,
          hasLikes: hasLikes,
          likes: likes,
          isfollowing: isfollowing,
          resault: resault
        });

      } else if ((likes.length < 0) && (resault.length > 0)) {
        res.render('single', {
          showPost: post,
          comments: comments,
          numComments: numComments,
          isfollowing: isfollowing,
          resault: resault,
          likes: likes
        });
        console.log('NO likes, has follows');

      } else if ((likes.length > 0) && (resault.length < 0)) {
        console.log('has likes, NO follows');
        res.render('single', {
          showPost: post,
          comments: comments,
          numComments: numComments,
          hasLikes: hasLikes,
          resault: resault,
          likes: likes
        });

      } else {
        console.log('has nothing');
        res.render('single', {
          showPost: post,
          comments: comments,
          numComments: numComments,
          resault: resault,
          likes: likes
        });

      }
      console.log(isfollowing);
      console.log(hasLikes);
    });

  });
}
```

Comment: what if `likes` is an empty array? that that case `likes[0]` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake.

I was using something like :

```
likes.length < 0
```

to check if the array is empty where I should have been using this:

```
!likes.length
```